# Maximize picks from a list when you can only choose 2 items from every 7 items

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

What would be an O(n) algorithm to maximize picks from a list when you can only choose 2 items from every 7 items. I've been thinking about this problem for a few days and I can't figure out an answer. I know it has to be a dynamic programming solution but I can't see how to relate any subproblems. I.e. if you have 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 20. Then at the end you want to pick 2, 4, 20, but 2 and 4 were never a solution before together.

Comment: Do you mean you want the best pick from the first 7, then the best pick from the next 7?  If so, why not take 3,4, 20?  
Or do you work in reverse, the best 2 from the last 7 etc.?

Comment: In any 7 day period in that list you can't pick more than 2

Comment: So like in 2,1,1,1,3,4,1 you can't pick more than two and also in 1,1,1,3,4,1,20

Comment: Ok, that creates a nice puzzle.

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question to make it reasonably answerable here.  For example, what is the picking criteria?  Is it a 7-item sliding window, or do you just check the data in contiguous chunks of 7 items?

Comment: If you're just given a long list of n numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your [comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/369993/maximize-picks-from-a-list-when-you-can-only-choose-2-items-from-every-7-items#comment810831_369993)

> So like in 2,1,1,1,3,4,1 you can't pick more than two and also in 1,1,1,3,4,1,20 – Paula

I conclude we are talking about a 7-item [sliding window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269948/1493294).

This 8 item list

```
[2,1,1,1,3,4,1,20]
```

will have two 7-item windows

```
[2,1,1,1,3,4,1]
  [1,1,1,3,4,1,20]
```

from each we can pick 2 items. We want to "maximize" these picks.

I assume this means you want to maximize the average of the picked numbers.

If "you can only pick 2 items" actually means you must always pick exactly 2 items then I can see how you get 2, 4, and 20. In the first window you choose 2 and 4, in the second window you pick 4 and 20. 4 gets picked twice.

If you meant we can pick up to 2 then I'd never have picked 2 or 4. Just 20. That leaves me with a much higher average. I'd only pick a number if it was about to leave the window and was the highest in the window (because this is the last chance to pick it while I have the most info about it) or if this is the last window I'll take the best number.

Since your solution isn't [20], it's [2,4,20] I assume we must choose exactly 2 for each window. In which case it's simple. In every 7 pick the top two numbers and don't double list the ones you pick twice.

Dynamic programming is not required for this.